# PyGtk, The Widget that have default choice like RadioButton

Tags: pygtk

How to Create RadioButton object that have default choice? perhaps there is a another way than my way. I want to share the class I created. my widget is `SpecificToggleWidget` i hope, maybe can useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

this is The `SpecificToggleWidget`. code of this module and example are very long so i shared link instead of sharing in here.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByGGW28GJgmod1ROMUxVQzd0RE0?usp=sharing